# CountDownTimer добавить время

Tags: android, время

Создал таймер обратного отсчета, хотелось бы чтоб по клику к оставшемуся времени прибавлялось, скажем еще 15 секунд. Как это реализовать?

вот код таймера:

```
  myTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 500) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

             if ( millisUntilFinished < timeBlinkInMilliseconds ) {
                 timer.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.blinkText);

                 if ( blink ) {
                    timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 } else {
                     timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 }

                 blink = !blink;        
             }
             timer.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             timer.setText("Время вышло!");
             timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Сосздайте класс на основе AsyncTask. В своём классе добавьте поле, которое будет хранить текущее количество секунд и метод, который будет добавлять 15 к этому полю. А в методе doInBackGround реализуйте цикл while (seconds > 0) { /* основная работа */} . Вывод чего-то на экран (например, сообщение "Время вышло") должно выполняться в методе onPostExecute.

Comment: Если есть желание использовать именно CountDownTimer, то нужно делать так

 - запомнить текущее состояние таймера
 - сделать ему `cancel`
 - рассчитать новое значение таймера (добавив 15 секунд или как там нужно)
 - запустить новый таймер с рассчитанными значениями.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы. Есть еще один вопрос. Возможно ли перезагрузить таймер, по клику например?

Comment: а что Вы понимаете под словами "перезагрузить таймер"? запустить его по новой?

Comment: Да, чтобы он сбросился на начальную позицию

Comment: просто сделайте ему cancel и создайте новый.